# Docker и базовые образы с разными дистрибутивами Linux

Tags: docker

Здравствуйте, понять не могу. 
Возьмем два докер файла:

Первый Dockerfile:

```
# Основано на debian:jessie
FROM mysql:5.7
```

Второй Dockerfile:

```
# Основано на Ubuntu
FROM stefobark/sphinxdocker
```

Или так:

```
version: '2'

services:
   mysql:
     image: mysql:5.7
   sphinx:
     image: stefobark/sphinxdocker
```

Будут скачаны две ОС? Разве это есть хорошо.

Что делать, не использовать офф. образы?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33322103/4827341

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Отредактировал.